# Eclipse Luna Error while running an application

Tags: eclipse-luna

I am facing the below issue while doing a fresh build or while running an application.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /D:/Eclipse_Luna/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/855/0/.cp/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZOT.png)

Comment: Sorry for the above post, the error  faced while running maven install

Comment: Please paste comeplete error here, off site resources tend to get removed and then the question means nothing to others

Answer (score 0):

I also got the similar error after  using eclipse.exe in command prompt for publshing the bundles. just eclipse->File->re-start the eclipse it works.